# Dynamics 365 Flow send email to primary contact

Tags: power-automate, dynamics-365

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to create a flow that sends emails to Primary contact of a case in Dynamics 365 using Power Automate.

I am not able to populate the email address for the user.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could a couple of Get row by id actions to retrieve the data of the related tables (Accounts and Contacts).

Below is an example setup.

*Use the Customer (Value) for Accounts and the Primary Contact (Value) for Contacts.*

[image]